# Red Project, Blue Project, Small Project, Large Project? What's the Point?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed these tags:

[large-project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-project) and [small-project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-project)

What's the purpose for these?

P.S. Can we have puns for tag questions here too? (With this one, I tried...)

Comment: I feel like the usage here would be relative (e.g. large or small relative to what?). That doesn't seem like a good thing.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this pop up while looking at the tags, and I was completely confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm am going to remove these tags. Not only don't they seem to serve a purpose, the questions that use them are not about being "large-projects" or "small-projects" at all.

Comment: Oh. Great! Thanks!